# How to create 2 textboxes that interacts with each other on text change?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create 2 text boxes which are the percentage of the discount and the discount applied. The logic I'm trying to achieve is that both values in the text boxes can be altered and if `percent` box is altered, the `discount` applied will be calculated with a simple equation `Discount = SubTotal * (Percent / 100);`. If `discount` box is altered, the percentage will be calculated instead with this simple equation `Percent = Discount / SubTotal * 100;`. However the current version I have can't work both ways, I always have to disable one of the equations. The known problem is that as I change the value of `discount` which should calculate the value of `percent`, before i have the chance to finish my entry, `Discount = SubTotal * (Percent / 100);` calculation will be carried out, causing my `discount` to stay at 0 and unable to escape this loop. This works vice versa on `percent` depending which equation is above and will be run first.

C#:

```cs
PercentChangedCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(() =>
{
    CalculateData();
});

DiscountChangedCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(() =>
{
    CalculateData();
});

private void CalculateData()
{
    SubTotal = amount + Price1 + Price2;
    Discount = SubTotal * (Percent / 100);  //Calculation for Discount if Percentage text box alters
    Percent = Discount / SubTotal * 100;    //Calculation for Percentage if Discount text box alters
    GST = SubTotal * 0.07;
    TotalAmount = SubTotal - Discount + GST;
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="4" ColumnDefinitions="0.7*,1*">
    <Frame Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FrameStyleBlack2}">
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
            <OnPlatform.Android>
                <customstyle:EntryBorderless
                    Keyboard="Numeric"
                    Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle2}"
                    Text="{Binding Percent, StringFormat='{0:F0}'}">
                    <customstyle:EntryBorderless.Behaviors>
                        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding PercentChangedCommand}" EventName="TextChanged"/>
                    </customstyle:EntryBorderless.Behaviors>
                </customstyle:EntryBorderless>
            </OnPlatform.Android>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Frame>
    <Frame Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource FrameStyleBlack2}">
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
            <OnPlatform.Android>
                <customstyle:EntryBorderless
                    Keyboard="Numeric"
                    Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle2}"
                    Text="{Binding Discount, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}">
                    <customstyle:EntryBorderless.Behaviors>
                        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding DiscountChangedCommand}" EventName="TextChanged"/>
                    </customstyle:EntryBorderless.Behaviors>
                </customstyle:EntryBorderless>
            </OnPlatform.Android>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am not sure but here Loop is concern - right?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding the commands to the "TextChanged" event you should implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your view model. That way you can control if and when the texts are updated (for example only if the new text is different than the current text).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle with `Property Changed` event and avoid `TextChanged` event

something like below...

```
private bool _discount;
public bool Discount
{
    get
    {
        return _discount;
    }
    set
    {
        _discount = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Discount");
        if(!IsCalculating)
            CalculateData();
    }
}

private bool _percent;
public bool Percent
{
    get
    {
        return _percent;
    }
    set
    {
        _percent = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Percent");
        if(!IsCalculating)
            CalculateData();
    }
}

bool IsCalculating = false;

private void CalculateData()
{
    bool IsCalculating = true;
    
    // Your Code
    
    bool IsCalculating = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. According to your writing, when you change the percentage, it will trigger CalculateData() to modify the value of discount, and if discount is worth modifying, it will trigger CalculateData(), thus causing an endless loop.
2. You can use Entry.Completed Event to avoid this from happening, by using the Completed event instead of CalculateData().